# Solve the analysis problem topics related to matrices

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, analysis, inverse-function

Let $M_n(\mathbb R)$ be the set of all real $n \times n$ matrices. Let $S$ be the subset of $M_n(\mathbb R)$ containing all invertible matrices. We consider a map $T:S \to S$ given by

$T(A) = A^{-1}$.

Show that the derivative of $T$ at $A \in S$ is given by 
$Gradient  T(A)(B) = -A^{-1} B A^{-1}$ for $B \in M_n(\mathbb R)$.

Since I couldn't solve the problem, I asked the professor and got a hint:

If you identify $M_n(\mathbb R)$ with $\mathbb R^{n^2}$, then you will see that $S$ can be identified as $\mathbb R^{n^2} \backslash \det^{-1} (0)$, i.e, an open subset of $\mathbb R^{n^2}$. Hence, $Gradient T(A) \in \mathcal L(\mathbb R^{n^2}; \mathbb R^{n^2})$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your professor's hint is a good one. Usually the derivative of matrix inverse is derived using first-order approximation (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Derivative_of_the_matrix_inverse), for instance). In this way the proof is coordinate-free.

Identifying $M_n(\mathbb R)$ with $\mathbb R^{n^2}$, IMHO, only complicates things and it brings along a bunch of indices. If you really want to go this way, see the proof on [planetmath.org](http://planetmath.org/derivativeofinversematrix).

Comment: then, can you show me other method to solve this problem since I don't have to follow the hint?

Comment: @Legendary The proofs are already in the links.

Comment: Does that mean gradient A = B ? following the Wikipedia source you attached...

Comment: @Legendary Hmm, no. As the problem statement says, $DT(A)(B)=-A^{-1}BA^{-1}$, i.e. $DT(A)$ is the linear map $B\mapsto -A^{-1}BA^{-1}$. Note that $DT$ is a mapping that maps every matrix $A$ to a linear map $DT(A)$ (the input is a matrix and the output is a linear map). I have no idea why you have edited $DT$ to $GradientT$. The function $T$ is matrix-valued, not real-valued. There is no gradient to talk about.

Comment: Oh. Thank you very much!! Your answer was so helpful!!